# RASA pip installation fail: Multiple requirements incompatible

Tags: rasa-core, rasa, rasa-x

I am trying to install RASA using instructions [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/installation/?_ga=2.56956650.1934376128.1587945113-945096393.1587945113#installation-guide)

I created a virtual environment and did a pip install rasa. But below is the error message with multiple dependencies incompatible. Do I install all the specified versions from the error message individually?

I found multiple people having installation issues and tried my best to find a solution in the forum, but couldn't.

[error message- list of dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBYTS.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to install Rasa1.x in an environment where you had previously installed rasa-nlu and rasa-core separately (pre Rasa 1.x). These are old versions that you can't mix with post-1.x Rasa.
I would recommend creating a new virtual environment, making sure it is active, checking that no `rasa-nlu` or `rasa-core` is installed, then running `pip install -U rasa` or `pip install -U rasa==<rasa version that you want>` if you want a specific version.